# Is there any references to this optimization problem？

Tags: matrix-calculus

Suppose that $\mathbf{a}$ is a $N$-dimentional column vector and $\mathbf{a}=[a_1,a_2,...,a_N]^{T}$, here $a_i \ge 0 $ for $i\in [1,N]$ and $\mathbf{W}$ is a symmetry matrix. I want to ask if there is any reference on how to solve the following optimization problems?
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    &\min_{\mathbf{a}}\quad \mathbf{a}^{T}\mathbf{W}\mathbf{a}, \\
    &\text{subject to} \quad \mathbf{1}^{T}_{N} \mathbf{a}=1, a_{i} \ge 0.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Here $\mathbf{1}^{T}_{N}$ is a $N$-dimentional column vector with all 1's element, e.g. $\mathbf{1}_{N}=[1,1,...,1]^{T}$. I found a reference [1] where he said that the closed solution to this problem is

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    \mathbf{a} = \frac{\mathbf{W}^{-1} \mathbf{1}_N}{\mathbf{1}_N^{\mathrm{T}} \mathbf{W}^{-1} \mathbf{1}_N}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
However, I'm confused about this, because $\mathbf{W}$ is just a symmetric matrix, $\mathbf{W}^{-1}$ may be not existed, so we don't necessarily have closed form solutions. Is there a better way to solve this problem?

[1] Zhao, Xiaochuan, and Ali H. Sayed. "Clustering via diffusion adaptation over networks." 2012 3rd International Workshop on Cognitive Information Processing (CIP). IEEE, 2012.

===========================Update================================
Thanks the reply for @cdalitz, and you are right. I want to talk about how I think this problem is solved.

From my opinion, I think the solution for this problem is complicated whether $\mathbf{W}$ is invertible or not.

1. When $\mathbf{W}$ is not invertible, as @cdalitz said, the solution is not unique, I'm not sure if we can solve it in the form of a pseudo-inverse matrix. But, at this point, I think a good method is to use the gradient descent method to solve.
2. When $\mathbf{W}$ is invertible, it's also very complicated to find the inverse of $\mathbf{W}$. I noticed that the paper[1] also provided an approximate solution by removing the non-diagonal elements of $\mathbf{W}$. I think the reason why he did like that is to make sure that $\mathbf{W}$ is invertible and to avoid solving for the inverse of $\mathbf{W}$.

Comment: The method for solving such problems is called "Lagrange Multipliers". A search for this term should point you to the solution.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know that we should use "Lagrange Multipliers" method to solve this problem, but I'm just wondering that symmetric metrice don't have to be invertible, which means that the solution may be not existed, so I am wondering if there is any mathematical literature on this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the matrix $W$ has a rank less than $N-1$, the solution will not be unique. Consider e.g. the case
$$W=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{array}\right)$$
The solution is any vector $\vec{a}=(a_1,a_2,0)^T$ with $a_1+a_2=1$, which are infinitely many. For rank $N-1$, I cannot immediately construct a similar example, but I guess the solution is ambigous in this case, too.

Comment: Thank you for your reply again. Combining with your answer, I added my own thoughts to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Linear algebra tells us there is a basis $\mathscr E = (\mathbf e_1, \mathbf e_2, \ldots, \mathbf e_n)$ in which the matrix of $W,$ in block matrix form, is

$$\operatorname{Mat}_{\mathscr E}(W) = \left(\begin{array}{c|c|c}\mathbf 1_r &  \mathbf 0_{r,s} & \mathbf 0_{r, n-r-s}\\
\hline \mathbf 0_{s,r} & -\mathbf 1_s & \mathbf 0_{s,n-r-s}\\
\hline \mathbf 0_{n-r-s,r} & \mathbf 0_{n-r-s,s} & \mathbf 0_{n-r-s}
\end{array}\right)$$

This basis can be found through any number of numerical diagonalization algorithms.  In this basis, where $\mathbf a = a_1 \mathbf e_1 + a_2 \mathbf e_2 + \cdots + a_n \mathbf e_n,$ the objective function is

$$f(\mathbf a) = \mathbf a^\prime \mathbf W \mathbf a = \sum_{i=1}^r a_i^2 - \sum_{j=1}^s a_{r+j}^2$$

and the constraint $\mathbf 1_n^\prime \mathbf a = 1$ will be expressed in the form

$$\mathbf \lambda^\prime \mathbf a = \lambda_1 a_1 + \lambda_2 a_2 + \cdots + \lambda_n a_n = 1$$

for some coefficients $\lambda_i$ not all of which are zero.

The rest is straightforward, because it is now clear how to minimize $f.$

You don't even need to use a Lagrange multiplier.  Instead, consider any arbitrary real numbers $u$ and $v.$  Minimize the sum of the squares of the first $r$ variables subject to the constraint $\lambda_1 a_1 + \cdots + \lambda_r a_r = u.$  (There's a simple formula for this.)  Separately, maximize the sum of the squares of the next $s$ variables subject to $\lambda_{r+1} a_{r+1} + \cdots + \lambda_{r+s} a_{r+s} = v.$  (Similar formula.)  Provided you can find $a_{r+s+1}, \ldots, a_{n}$ for which $\lambda_{r+s+1}a_{r+s+1} + \cdots + \lambda_n a_n = 1 - u - v,$ you have a potential solution.  This reduces your problem to the two variables $(u,v).$  The details depend on the pattern of zero coefficients in $\mathbf \lambda,$ so I won't belabor this point.

Comment: Hi, whuber, thank you for your answer. After reading your answer, I have a few questions (Please forgive me since I'm not very good at linear algebra):

1. Why the non-diagnoal elements of $\mathbf{W}$ are all zero in your hypothesis? Because from the problem we just know that W is a symmetric matrix, what if none of the entries in $\mathbf{W}$ are equal to zero?

2. I don't understand why the constraint $\mathbf{1}_{n}\mathbf{a}=1$ can be written in the form of $\mathbf{\lambda}\mathbf{a}=1$? Can you please explain it ?